# В чем разница между ORDER BY и GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, order-by

Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем разница между `order by` и `group by`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уж простите за прямоту, но ORDER - сортирует, а GROUP - группирует.